What is the dataflow refresh limit in Power BI?

A Power BI Premium subscription is required in order to refresh more
than 10 dataflows cross workspace.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/dataflows/dataflows-features-limitations
Question 1: Does this refer to parallel refresh limit? Or does this mean overall refresh limit? Or does this mean per day limit?
Question 2: Does dataflow have a maximum 8 times a day limit like dataset?

leaving the limitations of the type of Power BI subscription aside, each dataflow can be refreshed up to 48 times per 24 hours (once every 30 minutes).
There is a daily limit for each dataflow, the limits don't collide with other dataflow limits.
I hope I gave you some answers, you can look this information and more related to this in the Power BI official documentation --> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/dataflows/dataflows-features-limitations
